# Shielding Material of a cable

Tags: cables

I was reading one of your previous answers related with grounding of a cable. (Which was Suggesting whether cables should be grounded from both end or single end.)

I was wondering if you can think of a reason whether the type conducting material used for shielding has any effect on signals? Would it matter what kind of material you are using if you are doing single end grounding rather than both end?

Comment: In brief, the more conductive the shielding material, the better the shielding will be. Grounding at both ends is a bad idea regardless, so it's not clear what exactly your question is.

Comment: Grounding both ends, creates a "Ground Loop". That can burn out equipment from EMP (Lightning is an example).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The material itself does have an effect because of the change in resistivity between different materials creates a different potential between the two ends, and higher quality cables do tend to use more expensive materials with lower resistivity such as gold. Aluminum does do a relatively good job given its resistivity and the fact it is lightweight.

The major concert for most manufacturers is (as always) cost.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Considering cable grounded from one end; I assume this will induce standing voltage at the 'open end'. Can this be an issue for longer cables (which in my case it is about 100 meter)? Referring to Gustavo's comment; can this induced voltage difference vary depending on the shielding material? We are using copper as a shielding material and I am after the information whether would it be an issue to use another conductor with a lower conductivity? Regards.